# Laravel Eloquent How Can I Select Using Condition "where" for pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three database tables called user(id,name), group(id,name) and user_group(user_id, group_id,valid_before) with relations many to many.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'user_group')
               ->withPivot('valid_before');
    } 
}

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'group';

    public $timestamps = false;

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_group');
}
}
```

How can I select all users (using Eloquent)  who have

```
valid_before < $some_date
```

?

Comment: Does `valid_before` field belong to `user` table? If yes, you don't need pivot here. It will be like `select * from users where valid_before < some_date`

Comment: No, valid_before belongs to user_group table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this goal. I'll show you an example using [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#query-scopes).

In your `User` class you have to make a little update:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'user_group')
               //->withPivot('valid_before'); <-- Remove this
    }
}
```

and create a scope in your `Group` model:

```php
class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'group';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_group');
    }    

    /**
     * This scope gets as input the date you want to query and returns the users collection
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @param  string $date
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeUsersValidBefore($query, $date)
    {
        return $query->users()->wherePivot('valid_before', '<', $date);
    }
}
```

Now, I imagine you have a `GroupController` that somewhere creates a query to retrieve the *valid before* users. Something like:

```php
// [...]

$users = Group::usersValidBefore($yourDate)->get();

// [...]
```

If you want to create the query from the other side, I mean you want to use the User model and list all the Users that has a pivot relation with `valid_before` populated, than the right approach is creating a `UserGroup` [intermediate model](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) that can be easily used to create a query.

Comment: Query Scopes are not available in Laraval 8.x.x

Comment: @HarshalLonare yes they are. Have a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel 8.x.x

It's much easier with Inline Relationship Existence Queries

If you would like to query for a relationship's existence with a single, simple where condition attached to the relationship query, you may find it more convenient to use the whereRelation and whereMorphRelation methods. For example, we may query for all posts that have unapproved comments:

```
use App\Models\Post;

$posts = Post::whereRelation('comments', 'is_approved', false)->get();
```

Of course, like calls to the query builder's where method, you may also specify an operator:

```
$posts = Post::whereRelation(
    'comments', 'created_at', '>=', now()->subHour()
)->get();
```